# Module Questions

Tags: discussion

[Yesterday I had my question closed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32812/fooman-speedster-advanced-not-working-after-migration-to-1-9-from-1-8) and while I do understand that **questions about modules are not allowed**  I do NOT understand why **questions about modules specifically Fooman Modules have been allowed** in the past.

There is even a **fooman-extension** tag so:

Please explain OR mods get on the same page because I find it hypocritical that there are [other questions that were not closed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=fooman)

Either close them all, delete the tag  or allow them, make up your minds because it's not clear!

Comment: Who are you yelling at? We are people here trying to build a stronger platform, not a bunch of hippies trying to scam someone allowing some questions and closing others.

Comment: I'm looking for consistency. Click on the links and tell me that they are consistent.

Comment: Can you point me on the rule where said that module questions are not allowed?

Comment: It's lightly touched upon in the Help Center and I believe there is an option when flagging posts which would consider module questions "off topic" because it is not specifically about magento.

Comment: @sr_magento, do you think the questions are related: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/a/259/12293

Comment: @mbalparda I don't think you know what a "hippie" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at other questions about Fooman Modules, you will see that most of them are answered by Fooman himself.
If there are unanswered questions, I guess he did not see them, or for some reason did not want to answer them.
These should be also closed in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks Marius, but in my case the question was closed quickly and Fooman was not given the opportunity to respond in a timely manner.  He did respond the next day but in a comment.

Comment: @sr_magento. There...I voted to reopen it and asked fooman to write his comment as an answer. all good now?

Comment: Yes - I ultimately got my answer from the post, I do believe that others would benefit from it otherwise I would have resolved the issue on my own without posting it here. Anyway, thank you Marius :)